# Simulación de hilos. Java

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

**Simulación del paso de coches por un puente que tiene un sólo sentido:**

- El puente sólo acepta un máximo de 3 coches
- El puente soporta un peso máximo de 5000kg
- Cada coche pesa entre 800 y 2000 kg
- Cada coche llega al puente entre 1 y 30 segundos
- Cada coche tarda entre 10 y 50 segundos en pasar
- Para hacer la simulación, modelamos los coches como hilos
- El objeto puente, es un recurso compartido que controla el paso de todos los coches
- Dentro del puente, deberá haber un método sePermitePaso, que devuelve true/false dependiendo si acepta el paso de un coche.
- Cuando un coche salga, deberá modificar el estado del puente mediante un método llamado finalizarPaso
- Implementar la clase Puente, Coche y SimulacionPuente
- Usar el método sleep de Thread.
- Usar notifyAll(); en el run de la clase Coche

**Los atributos a usar son:**

*Clase Coche*:
(private int matricula, private int peso, referencia final recurso compartido(Puente), private int tPasarMaximo,private int tPasarMinimo) constructor y run.  pasar Mat, pasar peso, pasar tMinPaso y tMaxPaso, incrementa contador de matricula

*Clase SimulaPuente*:

- Main: objeto Puente puente (tLlegadaMin = 1, tLlegadaMax = 30, tMinPasar = 10, tMaxPasar = 50, pesoMin = 800, pesoMax = 2000, bucle infinito while (true), int Peso = calcular con random, calcular tiempo de llegada int tiempoLlegada = calcular con random, dormir main en try con tiempo de llegada y cuando despierte que cree hilos

*Clase Puente*:

private int cochesPasando maximo 3 inicializado a 0, private int pesoCochesPasando inicializado a 0, constante MAX_PESO = 5000, constante MAX_COCHES = 3, metodo booleano seAutorizaPaso sincronizado acepta como parametro, 1 coche (Coche coche) devuelve true cuando el numCoches<3 y peso+actual<=MAX_PESO contrario false. Metodo sincronizado finalizarPaso(Coche coche) decrementar el numero de coche y restar el peso del coche que sale.

Al hacer el ejercicio me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Ejercicio6.SimulaPuente.main(SimulaPuente.java:32)
```

En la clase SimulaPuente para el peso uso una funcion muy larga (a mi parece) me gustaría simplificarla con el `random r = new Random()` pero no se como hacerlo.

Pongo el código que tengo:
**Clase Coche**

```
public class Coche extends Thread{
    private int matricula;
    public int peso;
    final Puente puente;
    private int tPasarMaximo;
    private int tPasarMinimo;
    public long tiempo;

    public Coche(int matricula, int peso, Puente puente, int tPasarMaximo, int tPasarMinimo, long tiempo) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.puente = puente;
        this.tPasarMaximo = tPasarMaximo;
        this.tPasarMinimo = tPasarMinimo;
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if (puente.setAutorizoPaso(this)){
            try {
                sleep(tiempo);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            puente.finalizarPaso(this);
            synchronized (this){
                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase Puente**

```
public class Puente {
    private int cochesPasando = 0;
    private int pesoCochesPasando = 0;
    final int MAX_PESO = 5000;
    final int MAX_COCHES = 3;
    public int getCochesPasando(){
        return cochesPasando;
    }
    synchronized public boolean setAutorizoPaso(Coche coche){
        if (coche.peso+pesoCochesPasando<=MAX_PESO && cochesPasando<MAX_COCHES){
            cochesPasando++;
            pesoCochesPasando+=coche.peso;
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
    synchronized public void finalizarPaso(Coche coche){
        cochesPasando--;
        pesoCochesPasando-=coche.peso;
    }
}
```

**Clase SimulaPuente**

```
public class SimulaPuente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puente puente = new Puente();
        Random r = new Random();
        int matricula=1 ;
        int tLlegadaMinimo = 1;
        int tLlegadaMax = 30;
        int tMinPasar = 10;
        int tMaxPasar = 50;
        int pesoMin = 800;
        int pesoMax = 2000;

        while (true){
            int peso = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*(pesoMax-pesoMin)+pesoMin);
            long tiempoEnPasar = Math.round(Math.random()*(tMaxPasar-tMinPasar)+tMinPasar);
            Coche coche = new Coche(matricula,peso,puente,tMinPasar,tMaxPasar,tiempoEnPasar);
            try {
                int tiempoDeLlegada = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*(tLlegadaMinimo-tLlegadaMax)+tLlegadaMinimo);
                Thread.sleep(tiempoDeLlegada);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            coche.start();
            System.out.println("Hay " +puente.getCochesPasando()+ " coches pasando");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _Algún error_ es una descripción muy vaga. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y pon la traza del error, tan completa como creas conveniente.

Comment: @Alfabravo ya he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que estén invertidos los valores en la línea

```
int tiempoDeLlegada = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*(tLlegadaMinimo-tLlegadaMax)+tLlegadaMinimo);
```

teniendo en cuenta que

```
int tLlegadaMinimo = 1;
int tLlegadaMax = 30;
```

Significa que ese tiempo sería un random, multiplicado por `(1-30)+1`. Suena a que siempre es negativo. ¿No será que la resta es al revés?

Comment: Eso era gracias! Sabrías decirme como puedo hacer que el int peso =  ..; se haga con el random r en vez de como lo tengo en mi código ??

Comment: @marina Siempre comienza por revisar la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Usa los métodos de la clase que estás instanciando (que es `Random`) para que puedas obtener tu número pseudoaleatorio. En `r` no tienes ningún número, sólo un generador de pseudoaleatorios...

Comment: Vale.. gracias!

Comment: El "problema" que tengo ahora es que me sale todo el rato que hay 3 coches pasando y muy poco que hay 1 o 2 coches

Comment: @marina si tienes otra pregunta, abre otra pregunta con el código modificado. Si la respuesta te resolvió la duda, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Los comentarios no son para resolver otras preguntas